# Windows boost asio: 10061 in async_receive_from on on async_send_to

Tags: windows, network-programming, udp, boost-asio

I have a fairly large application that works as desired on Linux. I've recently compiled it on Windows 7 using VC2012 and boost asio 1.52 and run into a strange issue:

An `async_receive_from` followed by an `async_send_to` on the same UDP socket results in the read completion handler being called with `boost::system::error_code` 10061:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

*if* the send destination is another port on the local host. If the packet is sent to another machine, the read completion handler is not called. After the read completion handler, the write completion handler is called with no error.

The following code replicates the issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::asio;

void read_completion_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_received)
{
  if (!ec)
    cout << "Received " << bytes_received << " successfully" << endl;
  else
    cout << "Error: " << ec.message() << endl;
}

void write_completion_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
  if (!ec)
    cout << "Wrote " << bytes_transferred << " successfully" << endl;
  else
    cout << "Error: " << ec.message() << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  enum
  {
    max_length = 1500,
    out_length = 100
  };
  // buffer for incoming data
  char data[max_length];
  // outgoing data
  char out_data[out_length];

  // sender endpoint
  ip::udp::endpoint sender_endpoint;
  // for sending packets: if this localhost, the error occurs
  ip::udp::endpoint destination(ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 5004);

  io_service ioService;
  ip::udp::socket socket(ioService, ip::udp::endpoint(ip::udp::v4(), 49170));

  socket.async_receive_from(
    buffer(data, max_length), sender_endpoint,
    boost::bind(&read_completion_handler, 
    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

  socket.async_send_to( boost::asio::buffer(out_data, out_length),
    destination,
    boost::bind(&write_completion_handler,
    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

  ioService.run();

  cout << "Done" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

On linux this is never an issue. Does anyone have an explanation? As far as I know, simultaneous reads and writes on the same socket should be ok or is this not the case on Windows? Why the change in behaviour if localhost is the destination?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's about 6 months after you asked this question. I'm not even sure how I ended up here. I ran into this problem myself -- but the good news is that it's not a problem.

Some machines return a Destination Unreachable message through ICMP when they aren't listening on the port you sent your message to. Asio translates this to boost::system::errc::connection_refused and/or boost::system::errc::connection_reset. This is a meaningless error since UDP is connectionless. You can safely ignore these two error codes in your async_receive_from handler (ie, if you get one of these errors returned, just call async_receive_from again).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response and for explaining the asio error code translation. That makes sense. It's good to know that someone else ran into a similar issue. What doesn't quite add up for me though is why the write caused the read to fail? Is that an asio bug? Can you shed any light on that?

Comment: Hello there! 2 years later and I find your thread. I'm encountering the same issue! 
UDP seems to do this kind of thing when the host (usually on the same machine 127.0.0.1) tries to send data and there isn't anything on that port to listen for it.

Happens in C# as well as Boost::Asio C++. To fix this in C# you can write this code: 

            byte[] byteTrue = new byte[4];
            byteTrue[byteTrue.Length - 1] = 1;
            m_udpClient.Client.IOControl(-1744830452, byteTrue, null);

Sorry but I don't know a solution for Boost Asio yet so just do a special case and ignore that error

Comment: Niether boost::system::errc::connection_refused pr case boost::system::errc::connection_reset are = 10061

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling on this, read the comment I made above to the first response.

However, if you are by any change encountering the same issue in C#, use this code to get rid of the behavior:

```
        byte[] byteTrue = new byte[4];
        byteTrue[byteTrue.Length - 1] = 1;
        m_udpClient.Client.IOControl(-1744830452, byteTrue, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable ICMP `PORT_UNREACHABLE` on UDP receive, set [SIO_UDP_CONNRESET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/winsock-ioctls#sio_udp_connreset-opcode-setting-i-t3) to `0` (not 1, like the other answer suggests):

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    struct winsock_udp_connreset {
      unsigned long value = 0;
      int name() { return -1744830452; /* SIO_UDP_CONNRESET */ }
      unsigned long* data() { return &value; }
    };
    winsock_udp_connreset connreset{0};
    socket.io_control(connreset);
#endif
```